# How to flip up shapes in shiny by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, r, user-interface, shiny, semantic-ui

I want to include a semantic shape element in my shiny app (shapes:
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/shape.html#/usage). 
I am able to construct the shape by using `shinyjs` and `shiny.semantic`.
But I don't know how to create a button that flips the shape by clicking on it.

Here an example:

Ui.R:

```
    library(shiny)

    # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    shinyUI(semanticPage(
      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

      div(class="ui text shape",
          div(class="sides",
              div(class="ui header side active","This side starts visible."),
              div(class="ui header side","This is yet another side"),
              div(class="ui header side","This is the last side")
          )
      ),
 tags$button(id="test",class="ui button","Flip")

      ))
```

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
#devtools::install_github("Appsilon/shiny.semantic")
library(shiny.semantic)
#devtools::install_github("Appsilon/highlighter")
library(highlighter)
jsCode <- "
$('.shape').shape();
$('.shape').shape('flip up');
$('test').shape('flip up');
"

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  runjs(jsCode)

})
```

This creates both the button and a shape, but how do I make the button flipping the shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this JS code:

```
jsCode <- "
$('.shape').shape();
$('#test').on('click', function(){$('.shape').shape('flip up');});
"
```

Or just:

```
jsCode <- "
    $('.shape').shape();
    "
```

and in the ui:

```
  tags$button(id="test", class="ui button", "Flip", onclick="$('.shape').shape('flip up');")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But if I put the button and the shape in a renderUI, the button does not work.

Comment: @R_FF92 Hmmm... maybe this deserves to open a new question.

Comment: @R_FF92 I've edited my post to include a second solution. Maybe this one works with a renderUI.

Comment: Yes. This works with render UI. Do you have some documentation which helps to understand this syntax? I think its a nice package but oftentimes I don't know where to put things in the code.

Comment: @R_FF92 In fact, this code has nothing to do with the package. `onclick` is a standard html attribute of buttons, and the syntax `$(...)` is the syntax of the jQuery library.